# CarrierWave: create 1 uploader for multiple types of files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I want to create 1 uploader for multiple types of files (images, pdf, video)

For each content_type will different actions

How I can define what content_type of file?

For example:

```
if image?
  version :thumb do
    process :proper_resize    
  end
elsif video?
  version :thumb do
    something
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came across this, and it looks like an example of how to solve this problem: https://gist.github.com/995663.

The uploader first gets loaded when you call `mount_uploader`, at which point things like `if image?` or `elsif video?` won't work, because there is no file to upload defined yet. You'll need the methods to be called when the class is instantiated instead.

What the link I gave above does, is rewrite the `process` method, so that it takes a list of file extensions, and processes only if your file matches one of those extensions

```
# create a new "process_extensions" method.  It is like "process", except
# it takes an array of extensions as the first parameter, and registers
# a trampoline method which checks the extension before invocation
def self.process_extensions(*args)
  extensions = args.shift
  args.each do |arg|
    if arg.is_a?(Hash)
      arg.each do |method, args|
        processors.push([:process_trampoline, [extensions, method, args]])
      end
    else
      processors.push([:process_trampoline, [extensions, arg, []]])
    end
  end
end

# our trampoline method which only performs processing if the extension matches
def process_trampoline(extensions, method, args)
  extension = File.extname(original_filename).downcase
  extension = extension[1..-1] if extension[0,1] == '.'
  self.send(method, *args) if extensions.include?(extension)
end
```

You can then use this to call what used to be process

```
IMAGE_EXTENSIONS = %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
DOCUMENT_EXTENSIONS = %(exe pdf doc docm xls)
def extension_white_list
  IMAGE_EXTENSIONS + DOCUMENT_EXTENSIONS
end

process_extensions IMAGE_EXTENSIONS, :resize_to_fit => [1024, 768]
```

For versions, there's a page on the carrierwave wiki that allows you to conditionally process versions, if you're on >0.5.4. https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Do-conditional-processing. You'll have to change the version code to look like this:

```
version :big, :if => :image? do
  process :resize_to_limit => [160, 100]
end

protected
def image?(new_file)
  new_file.content_type.include? 'image'
end
```

Comment: Another update ... figured out how to take care of selectively creating versions

Comment: Hi, looking for something exactly like this. Is there a simpler way to do this now? thanks

Comment: There's several newer versions of the carrierwave gem that might make it easier, but I don't know if they do or not. I just got it working for me and haven't gone back to look at it since then.

Comment: One more question, i'm using  uploader for all my uploads and in the form that handles the file upload i'm sending a parameter called upload_type to the model, upload_type can be("all","image","doc") etc. Can i intercept that upload_type parameter in this uploader class and use it as a condition in extension_white_list e.g. if upload_type == "image" IMAGE_EXTENSIONS elsif upload_type == "all" IMAGE_EXTENSIONS + DOCUMENT_EXTENSIONS?