# carrierwave - create thumb for pictures and videos in same uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am trying to create thumb for pictures or videos in the same uploader for an ad model...

So far, I am trying to create a conditional thumb like that:

```
  version :thumb do
      process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]   if %w(jpg jpeg gif png).include?(file.extension)    
      process :screenshot => 5 if %w(mpg avi).include?(file.extension)
    end
  end
```

but apparently, I get errors on the file.extension part like this

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `file'
```

Does anyone know how to get the file extension in uploader?

Comment: Sry mates :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519172/carrierwave-create-1-uploader-for-multiple-types-of-files?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks like the carrierwave generated uploader class and if I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a way to restrict the type of file that can be turned into a thumbnail. You can whitelist the types of files the uploader class will accept - so in the uploader class where your :thumb method is located include the following :

```
    # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
    # For images you might use something like this:
    def extension_white_list
      %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    end
```